# Cant apply snapshot on HyperV by Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotService

Tags: wmi, hyper-v, python-3.6

Then i try this:

```
wmiServerConnection = wmi.WMI(namespace=r'root\virtualization\v2')
vmSnapManagement = wmiServerConnection.Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotService()[0]
vmSystem = wmiServerConnection.Msvm_ComputerSystem(ElementName=r'wmname')[0]
vmObjects = vmSystem.associators(wmi_result_class='Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData')

for singleVmObject in vmObjects:
    if singleVmObject.ElementName == r'snapshotname':
        job = vmSnapManagement.ApplySnapshot(singleVmObject)
```

i get error:
wmi.x_wmi 
x_wmi: Unexpected COM Error (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'SWbemProperty', 'Type mismatch ', None, 0, -2147217403), None)

Answer (score 0):

This is in VB.Net (not Python), but hopefully this will push you in the right direction. This example applies the most recent snapshot, but to apply a specific snapshot, just get the Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData instance of the snapshot you wish to apply, and use that instance in place of 'lastSnapshot'.

```
Imports System.Management

Public Class VirtualSystemSnapshot
    Public Shared Function Revert(vmElementName As String)
        Dim scope As New ManagementScope("\\" & ServerName & "\Root\Virtualization\V2", Options)
        Using virtualMachine As ManagementObject = WmiUtilities.GetVirtualMachine(vmElementName, scope)
            Using virtualSystemSettingData As ManagementObject = WmiUtilities.GetVirtualSystemSettingData(scope, virtualMachine)
                Using virtualSystemSnapshotService As ManagementObject = WmiUtilities.GetVirtualSystemSnapshotService(scope)
                    Using lastSnapshot As ManagementObject = WmiUtilities.GetFirstObjectFromCollection(
                            virtualSystemSettingData.GetRelated("Msvm_VirtualSystemSettingData", "Msvm_ParentChildSettingData", Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, False, Nothing))
                        Using inParams As ManagementBaseObject = virtualSystemSnapshotService.GetMethodParameters("ApplySnapshot")
                            inParams("Snapshot") = lastSnapshot

                            ' In order to apply a snapshot, the virtual machine must first be saved
                            RequestStateChange.Main(vm, RequestedState.Save)

                            Using outParams As ManagementBaseObject = virtualSystemSnapshotService.InvokeMethod("ApplySnapshot", inParams, Nothing)
                                WmiUtilities.ValidateOutput(outParams, scope)

                                ' Now that the snapshot has been applied, start the VM back up
                                RequestStateChange.Main(vm, RequestedState.Start)
                            End Using
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```